# WPML + ACF - не сохраняет редактирование для нового языка

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

Добрый день.
Подскажите - есть связка на Wordpress: WPML + ACF.
При создании перевода для поста на другом языке, когда копирую содержимое - поля заполняются корректно. Однако при редактировании - их не удается отредактировать. Посмотрел код и увидел, что даже не идет запрос на изменение этих полей. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Только что попробовал - все работает. Какой код вы смотрели? Покажите картинку, где не удается редактировать.

Comment: Разобрался уже как - добавил еще модуль translation management . По умолчанию не хотело работать почему-то